# WPF : change scrollBar style

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar, expression-blend

I want to change ScrollBar Style like this picture.

How can I change ?

Have to make Template? Then, how?

[image]
Basic ScrollBar (Now)

[image]
I want to change like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using Expression Blend. A good tutorial for same can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41787/Creating-a-Blend-like-Scrollbar).

Comment: Glad to help you :)